# Devise: Logout not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have seen many questions about this topic, but nothing is helping. I added Bootstrap into my website and now my logout functionality isn't working.
I raked my routes and got this the line

`destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy`

so It's not getting confused as a GET. My logout code looks like `<li><%= link_to('Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need logout via GET you should add this inside `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

If you don't you should check your `application.js` file, it should include these lines:

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: `//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs` was my issue, thanks :D I'll check up this answer in 5 min